# Can I run Python 2.7 Libraries (Impacket, Pcapy) on Django

Tags: python

Hi I just want to ask if its possible to run Impacket to Django,

On my project I am already done on my sniffing and parsing using Impacket and Pcapy but my clients requested that the GUI will be web based. I picked Django because its the most widely used and all but I am having doubts that it can run my Libraries.

For starters can Django open my NIC in Ubuntu and have access to sniff on it?

or is it better for me to use Flask for from what I read flask is being run on the Python Console Application, from what I understood I will install a HTTP Server in the Project then the Python Console will be like a Controller (MVC) to my GUI which is Flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run anything from Django, it just provides a framework to get stuff to the web.

As long as the Django application is running as a user which has privileges to access your NIC there won't be an issue with that.

You can simply call your code you already have from the Django Views.

The time this stuff takes may be too long for a web request so you may need to pass some stuff down a message queue and look up the results. Look at Celery for that purpose.

I do prefer Flask over Django but it doesn't matter what you use.

Just remember Django is another library it all still runs inside Python :)

Comment: Oh, I am a developer of Microsoft so I have my hands on C# and ASP.Net which has different set of libraries. 

I never thought Python only has one, now I get why it is called portable :) 

THANKS!

Comment: Please be careful there however. Not all tools are available for Windows, it's not so widely used within the Python world so some libraries, especially low level ones may require *NIX features. See the docs for each library for more details. There are still C binding which will not always be portable.

Comment: How about Impacket, there are no decent documentation about it. as far as I know I need to have root permission for I will listen to NIC